# What is the difference between Citta contemplation and Dhamma contemplation in Satipathana?

Tags: theravada

What is Citta?
What is Dhamma?
What is the difference between above two in Satipathana?

Comment: https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-two-sitting-meditation/

Answer (score -1):

These are the two last stages in the [4 foundations of mindfulness](https://dhammawiki.com/index.php/4_Foundations_of_Mindfulness):

Citta means "mind". Dhamma refers to the Buddhist teachings.

Cittanupasana is the meditation on the mind: the observation of the arising and setting of thoughts and desires. It is required to understand the impermanent nature of mind, which is wrongfully perceived as a permanent self.

Dhammanupasana is meditation on the Dharma, the Buddhist teachings. Typically a student will be asked to meditate/research one of these topics:

- The Five Hindrances
- The Four Noble Truths
- The Seven Factors of Enlightenment
- The Five Aggregates
- Canon Literature

Comment: I don't think that this is a proper translation of the 4 Satipathanas. If we take your approach, how are we supposed to feel dispassion in Dhammanupassana? "Dhamma" in "Dhammanupassana" does not refer to the Buddha's teaching but rather about the 3 characteristics and the letting go (vosagga) of craving (tanha). The 4 Satipathanas are done in a chronological way. Once the Body and the Mind is tranquillized one is feeling rapture. Once rapture arises it is the object of meditation and one is in the vedana "realm".

Comment: Dispassion in the Dhammanupassana section clearly indicates that the Mind is that sharp, that is,without thoughts so that one can clearly see the impermanence of the 5 khandas and once the impermanence is seen, dispassion arises since they cannot be grasped. One ultimately lets go of the clinging since it is otherwise dukkha.